# Remote validation in login page not in register

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im having some issues using remote validation in ASP.NET:
Everything it's kind of working fine but my method is incorrectly considering the Login page to make the validation, instead of the registration page.

### AccountsControler

```
public JsonResult IsUserAvailable(string UserName) {
     using (LeafDbContext db = new LeafDbContext()) {
        return Json(!db.userAccount.Any(User => User.UserName == UserName),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
  }
```

*Note: AccountsController it's the same controller that I use to handle all the registration stuff (password hashing, send confirmation mail, etc.).*

### LoginUserAccount model

```
public class LoginUserAccount {
      //...bunch of other fields required for registration

      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Um nome de usuário é obrigatório.")]
      [Remote("IsUserAvailable","Accounts",ErrorMessage = "O usuário já existe.")]
      public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

*Note: The `ErrorMessage` it's in Portuguese, please ignore it.*

### Register.cshtml

```
@model LEAF.Models.LoginUserAccount
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <!-- bunch of other fields required for registration-->  

        <!-- and my UserName input right below -->

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

*Note: I'm using exctly the same code for the Login.cshtml (including the `@model LEAF.Models.LoginUserAccount`), but Login validation is being done by another controller.*

Well, that is working indeed, but incorrectly. When I run the application and it redirects to my login page, the remote validation it's being done there, on my UserName input, and not in my registration page. What should I do to change it to my registration page?

Comment: You should not have the same model for a Login and Register action (for a start, a Register action will need additional properties such as `ConfirmPassword`). Create 2 separate view models and views (with different validation attributes)

Comment: That actually came to my head when I was writing down the question. So, since Im using Code First, I should only use Dbset (in Dbcontext) for the `LoginUserAccount` and create another model for the login. Right?

Comment: No, You need to use view models, not data models in your view (have a look at the default models, controller and views generated when you create a new project using MVC

Comment: Note that viewmodels != data models, data models are actual classes reflecting DB table configuration & viewmodels are classes used to interact with view page. Better to create corresponding view & viewmodel linked with user DbSet properties for each action (login & register user).

Comment: That's what I'd call useful information. I'm kind of learning ASP NET and MVC by myself. So I have some knowledge gaps. Thanks guys. One last question: Should I use DataAnnotations in the ViewModels or in the Data Models?